# How do I auto sync files between my Android device and Windows PC over USB?

Tags: sync, usb, windows, files

Is there a software that can auto sync files from certain folders of our choice between Android device and Windows PC(Like the Camera folder or Music folder)? I am tired of manually copying those files using file explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyPhoneExplorer Look Like It solves your problem it's compatible with syncing over USB and best of all it's now ad free.
http://www.fjsoft.at/en/